# Best practice to create a template similar to existing but with different "Shared" value

Tags: sxa, templates

I am using `SXA` Map component on my page and using one template "Office POI". This template have shared fields like Street, City, Pin etc. Items created on this template works perfectly on Map but now I have a requirement where I need to show offices in different component and this component should support multilingual POIs. Since existing template have shared field it can't create multilingual POIs so I am considering to create a new template with fields that are not shared. I can duplicate existing template and uncheck Shared checkbox but that looks like violating "DRY" principle. Is there any better way to create such template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This flowchart <[Link here](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/93/sitecore-experience-accelerator/flowchart-to-determine-whether-to-create-a-custom-rendering.html)> helps make the decision in most cases on when to go for custom renderings.

In view of `Maps` I see your need to make the fields `UnShared` which would still fall into the category of Datasource customization as it is never a good practice to change the XA templates in first place.

It is ok to create a new template copy and then create a new `Map Localized` Rendering (cloned) with one edit on `Datasource Template` to point to your new template.

Keeping this simple not only gives benefit to extend the Maps to serve your purpose but also keeps your upgrades safe and easy serving the `sxa` core purpose of reusability and speed to production.(although not DRY :))

Comment: Thanks you Suneeth for shedding lights on it. I had to go this way only. "upgrade safe" makes much sense.